# Unable to get sms which is more than 160 characters from twilio and ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twilio

I am trying to send sms which has more than 160 characters and seen twilio api document where
recently they can support up to 1600 characters.

But I unable to get the sms more than 160 but able to get below 160 characters as I used
the latest gem twilio-ruby.

Its giving delivered status When I checked with api response for more than 160 characters.

Please let me know your ideas on it.

Comment: Hi, Twilio Evangelist here: are you using `client.account.sms` or `client.account.messages`? Only `messages` support over 1600 characters. Also, which country are you sending from and to?

Comment: Yeah, I found this change as I'm using the client.account.messages only. Shall my account need to have credits? as it showing status 'queue'.

Comment: Well, if you account doesn't have any credit, then it won't be able to send messages at all. Are you using a Trial account? Also, what country are you sending to/from?

Comment: Yes trail account, country is India .

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Evangelist here,

It sounds like there are a couple of issues  here. First of all I'd suggest you take a look at [this page](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/are-there-limitations-on-sending-sms-messages-to-indian-mobile-devices) about SMS to India. Basically, you need to be opted out of the Do Not Call Registry.

This should allow you to send SMS messages, but if the problem is only occurring with long (concat-) SMS then there may be some other issue.

I think the best option is to email help@twilio.com, and they can help figure it out. Remember to include your Twilio Account SID and the number you're using.